# How to compare "4A4B4C" (string shows hex value) actual string is "JKL"

Tags: c++, string, hex, string-comparison

I am getting a string `"4A4B4C4D4E4F"`.. it is equal to a string (`"JKLMNO"`)

How can I check this type of string in c++.. (one string shows the hexadecimal representation of another)

hexadecimal value of

```
J=4A, K=4B, L=4C
```

Comment: what approaches have you tried so far?

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5990825/convert-an-ascii-stdstring-to-hex/5990913#5990913 for converting a string to hex in C++

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alternatively this can be done using C++ strings and features rather than C-style strings:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>

bool compareAscii(const std::string& string, const std::string& asciistr) {
   std::ostringstream result;
   result << std::setw(2) << std::setfill('0') << std::hex << std::uppercase;
   // We copy the contents of string, using the range from the beginning to the end.
   // By copying it to an ostream iterator it gets written to the ostringstream,
   // but crucially we treat it as an unsigned int when we write it, which causes
   // the chars to get printed as their numerical values instead.
   std::copy(string.begin(), string.end(), std::ostream_iterator<unsigned int>(result));
   return result.str() == asciistr;
}

namespace {
   const std::string test="JKLMNO";
   const std::string value="4A4B4C4D4E4F";
}

int main() {
   std::cout << "compareAscii(\"" << test << "\", \"" << value << "\") returned " << compareAscii(test, value) << std::endl;
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: thanks for your code Mr awoodland... In that code i didnt understand what you are copying.. std::copy that line... can you explain that ..?

Comment: I like your answer. Just to improve it a little bit (though not requested by question) if you use std::showbase with your stream you can also get to see the hexadecimal base (i.e 0xA instead of A) which I think improves readability

Comment: @OrcunC - the problem with showbase here is the input string the OP showed doesn't have the 0xs anywhere in it.

Comment: @Balamurugan - I've added a comment in the code by the [`std::copy`](http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/copy.html) call. Hopefully that makes it clearer what's happening. Basically it's printing it into a string, using an `ostream_iterator` and setting up the printing such that it gets printed as a number in hex, converting it to match the hex input you showed and then comparing it.

Comment: @awoodland Yes I am aware of the fact that it was not requested. That is why I put the "(though not requested by question)" parenthesis to my comment. I just wanted to indicate that it was possible. Nothing more :-)

Comment: @OrcunC, sorry I missed that bit when I read your comment the first time. The std::showbase iomanip reference is handy too - I always forget the name of it.

Comment: Anyway you have +1 from me for using c++ string and stream classes.

Answer (score 2):

```
int hexcmp(const char *string, const char *hex_string)
{
    int len = strlen(string);
    char *hexed_string = new char[2*len+1];
    hexed_string[2*len] = '\0'; //  null-terminate
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
    {
        sprintf(hexed_string, "%X", string[i]);
        hexed_string += 2;
    }
    hexed_string -= 2*len;
    printf("%s\n", hexed_string);
    int res = strcmp(hexed_string, hex_string);
    delete hexed_string;
    return res;
}

if(!hexcmp("JKLMNO", "4A4B4C4D4E4F"))
    printf("Equal\n");
else
    printf("Nonequal\n");
```

Comment: This looks more like C than C++

Answer (score 1):

One way is to convert each two hex digits from your hex string and convert it into a decimal value and then compare this converted numeric with the ASCII value of the string you have to be compared.

A sample code is shown:

```
int main (void)
{
  char str1[]="4A4B4C4D4E4F";
  char str2[]="JKLMNO";
  char buffer[3];
  int n, i = 0, j = 0, value, flag = 1;

  n = strlen (str1);
  while (i<n)
  {
    buffer[0] = str1[i++];
    buffer[1] = str1[i++];
    buffer[2] = '\0';
    value = strtol (buffer, NULL, 16);
    if (str2[j] != value)
    {
      flag = 0;
      break;
    }
    j++;
  }

  if (flag)
    printf ("\nMatch");
  else
    printf ("\nNo Match");

  printf ("\n");
  reutrn 0;
}
```

Comment: This looks more like C than C++

Comment: actually it is in C. i just wanted to convey a logic to the asker