# Handling of conversions from and to hex

Tags: c++, hex, ascii

I want to build a function to easily convert a string containing hex code (eg. "0ae34e") into a string containing the equivalent ascii values and vice versa.
Do I have to cut the Hex string in pairs of 2 values and gue them together again or is there a convenient way to do that?

thanks

Comment: [`std::hex`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/manipulators/hex/) should do the trick.

Comment: What, precisely, do you mean by "string"? `std::string`? Nul-terminated `const char*`? Something else?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Convert an ASCII std::string to hex](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5990825/convert-an-ascii-stdstring-to-hex)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on [`binascii_unhexlify()`](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/3.2/Modules/binascii.c#l1115) function from Python:

```
#include <cctype> // is*

int to_int(int c) {
  if (not isxdigit(c)) return -1; // error: non-hexadecimal digit found
  if (isdigit(c)) return c - '0';
  if (isupper(c)) c = tolower(c);
  return c - 'a' + 10;
}

template<class InputIterator, class OutputIterator> int
unhexlify(InputIterator first, InputIterator last, OutputIterator ascii) {
  while (first != last) {
    int top = to_int(*first++);
    int bot = to_int(*first++);
    if (top == -1 or bot == -1)
      return -1; // error
    *ascii++ = (top << 4) + bot;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

#### [Example](http://ideone.com/o4boW)

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
  char hex[] = "7B5a7D";
  size_t len = sizeof(hex) - 1; // strlen
  char ascii[len/2+1];
  ascii[len/2] = '\0';

  if (unhexlify(hex, hex+len, ascii) < 0) return 1; // error
  std::cout << hex << " -> " << ascii << std::endl;
}
```

#### Output

```
7B5a7D -> {Z}
```

An interesting quote from the comments in the source code:

> While I was reading dozens of programs that encode or decode the
> formats here (documentation? hihi:-) I have formulated Jansen's
> Observation:
>
> Programs that encode binary data in ASCII are written in such a style
> that they are as unreadable as possible. Devices used include
> unnecessary global variables, burying important tables in unrelated
> sourcefiles, putting functions in include files, using
> seemingly-descriptive variable names for different purposes, calls to
> empty subroutines and a host of others.
>
> I have attempted to break with this tradition, but I guess that that
> does make the performance sub-optimal. Oh well, too bad...
>
> Jack Jansen, CWI, July 1995.

Comment: simply works. thank you! but the answer to my question is no :(

Answer (score 0):

The `sprintf` and `sscanf` functions can already do that for you. This code is an example that should give you an idea. Please go through the function references and the safe alternatives before you use them

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
 int i;
 char str[80]={0};
 char input[80]="0x01F1";
 int output;
 /* convert a hex input to integer in string */
 printf ("Hex number: ");
 scanf ("%x",&i);
 sprintf (str,"%d",i,i);
 printf("%s\n",str);
/* convert input in hex to integer in string */
 sscanf(input,"%x",&output);
 printf("%d\n",output);
}
```

Comment: The `std::stream` functions can do it too using the `hex` modifier.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use a more c++ native way, you can say

```
std::string str = "0x00f34" // for example

stringstream ss(str);

ss << hex;

int n;

ss >> n;
```

Comment: how do you convert `"68656C6C6F20776F726C64"` to `"hello world"` with this code?

Comment: sometimes you cant see the forest for the trees. I had something similar, but it didn't work. Thank you

Comment: Why didn't it work? Did you get any errors? Perhaps you forgot to include `sstream` and `iomanip`?

Comment: sorry for not answering. The problem with this code is the reason I asked the question. I am unable to get a string out of that. Another problem is that I am unable to use long strings, because the size of an int is limited.

Comment: To get a string out of a string stream like `ss` above use the the `str()` method: `ss.str()`. You may want to check out the [cplusplus](http://www.cplusplus.com/) site. It has lots of useful references and tutorials. About the long strings I'm not sure what the issue is. If your strings are too long you have to figure out what to do with them.