# Convert to ASCII String from hex String in C

Tags: c, string, ascii

I am trying to convert a hex string to its equivalent ASCII. I am given a "hex" value of a string as a string, i.e instead of "ABCD" I get "41424344". I just need to extract 41 which will be my hexvalue and recode as "ABCD". Here is what I have.

```
   int main(int argc, char *argv[]){

    char *str = "ABCD";
    unsigned int val = 0;
    int i = 0;
    int MAX = 4;
    for (i = 0; i<MAX; i++){
        val = (str[i] & 0xFF);
        //printf("dec val= %d\n", val);
        //printf("hex val= %02x\n", val);
    }
    val = 0;
    char *hexstr = "41424344";
    char *substr = (char*)malloc(3);
    char *ptr = hexstr;

    for (i = 0; i<8; i++){
        strncpy(substr, ptr, 2);
        printf("substr = %s\n", substr);
        int s = atoi(substr);
        printf("s= %d\n", s);
        ptr= ptr+2;
        i = i+2;
    }
    return 0;

}
```

The thing is from here on, I have to make this "s" value to be a hex value and not an int. How can this be done?

**UPDATE:**

Here is what I have after your answers:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
int main(int argc, char *argv[]){

    char *str = "ABCD";
    unsigned int val;
    val = 0;
    int i = 0;
    int MAX = 4;
    for (i = 0; i<MAX; i++){
        val = (str[i] & 0xFF);
        //printf("dec val= %d\n", val);
        //printf("hex val= %02x\n", val);
    }
    val = 0;
    char *hexstr = "41424344";
    char *substr = (char*)malloc(3);
    char *ptr = hexstr;
    char *retstr = (char *)malloc(5);
    char *retptr = retstr;

    for (i = 0; i<8; i+1){
        strncpy(substr, ptr, 2);
        printf("substr = %s\n", substr);
        int s = strtol(substr, NULL, 16);
        printf("s= %d\n", s);
        ptr= ptr+2;
        i = i+2;
        sprintf(retptr, "%c", s);
        retptr = retptr +1;
    }
    printf("retstr= %s\n", retstr);
    return 0;

}
```

Comment: you have strtol to convert a string in an other base and %x or %X in printf to display an hexa value

Comment: Allocate 3 bytes for `substr`. Forgot `'\0'` ??

Comment: related: [Handling of conversions from and to hex](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9620891/4279)

Comment: Thanks Jeyaram! silly me :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your "s" variable line from

`int s = atoi(substr);`

to

`int s = strtol(substr, NULL, 16);`

Comment: `substr` doesn't have a nul terminator so the return from `atoi` will still be undefined

Comment: yeah, also there's an interesting typo in the for loop increment step. `i+i`. anyway updated the answer hope it helps

Comment: hi sudopunk, why do I get a warning in the for loop statement: statement has no effect?

Comment: your loop needs to assign a value to i.  `(i = 0; i<8; i+1)` should be changed to `(i = 0; i<8; i=i+2)` and you should remove the following statement inside the for loop `i = i+2;`